# Distorted background by models

Tags: image, transparency, distort

A really beginner here. I’m trying to figure out how to distort a background image with a model in front with a shading like water or even glass. I read a similar answer here before but when I tried to apply it, didn’t worked.

I have a background image in the camera and it’s locked to view. Attached: Compositing, Shading and Rendered image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend you do not use the compositor for this. Instead, set up the hello world image as a world background, and use the Texture Coordinate node -> Window (I think) to make the image always exactly fill the camera view. Finally, change the object’s materials to Glass BSDF.

Comment: Thank you! Helped me a lot.

Comment: @AndréBarreto You’re welcome. :-) checkmark it as an accepted answer, then.

Comment: @AndréBarreto (I get points if you do ☺️)